# Email template table showing spacing in mobile devices

Tags: html-email

I have created a custom email template and the content is below :

```
...
<table id="Table_01" width="70%" border="0" cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0"  style=" backgroud:red;border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <img style="display:block; border: 0px;width:100%;" src="images/01.png"  alt="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <table id="Table_02" width="100%"  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=" border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img style="display:block; border: 0px;width:100%;" src="images/02_01.png"  alt="">
                    </td>
                    <td >
                        <img style="display:block; border: 0px;width:100%;" src="images/02_03.png" alt="">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <img style="display:block; border: 0px;width:100%;" src="images/03.png"  alt="">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
...
```

Above code created a table with three `tr` and it is showing properly in desktop but in mobile devices showing some spacing.

[image]

As above image table showing red line spacing in mobile devices.

How to remove these spacing?

Answer (score 0):

**It helps to include a few CSS resets in the `<head>` of the email.**Here are a few that I use the focus on resetting spacing and borders of `<table>`s and `<td>`s:

```
<head>
    <style>
        /* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */
        table {
            border-spacing: 0 !important;
            border-collapse: collapse !important;
            table-layout: fixed !important;
            margin: 0 auto !important;
        }
        table table table {
            table-layout: auto; 
        }

        /* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */
        table,
        td {
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Here is the [full CSS reset I use for emails](https://github.com/TedGoas/Cerberus/blob/master/cerberus-fluid.html).